# How to resolve 'Error: Cannot find module 'request' Require stack:' running JS Code in Zapier

Tags: javascript, api, integration, zapier

I'm trying to complete an integration using Zapier's JS Code action and one of their predefined triggers. In this example I'm using their HubSpot tool to trigger whenever a new contact is created and to initiate a POST containing their data, creating the same contact in the other software. I copied the NodeJS Request below from Postman where it works correctly:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'https://examplewebsite.com/authtoken',
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "LeadInfo": "Lead Info",
    "CustomerFID": null,
    "RegCommunityFID": "202",
    "NameLast": "Bobby",
    "NameMiddle": "N",
    "NameFirst": "INTEGRATION2",
    "Title": "Mr",
    "NameLast2": "TEST",
    "NameMiddle2": "K",
    "NameFirst2": "Bo",
    "Title2": "",
    "Suffix2": "",
    "StreetAddress": "Batman Plaza",
    "City": "Illinois",
    "ZipCode": "12345",
    "StateCode": "IL",
    "PhoneHome": "(889) 442-0124",
    "EmailHome": "integrationstest2@testmail.com",
    "Rating": "Rating",
    "LeadSource": "LeadSource",
    "RegistrationNotes": "string",
    "ExternalID": "EXID",
    "Status": "Status",
    "ProspectNumber": "2",
    "WCCustBuyerInfo": {
      "ContractName": "ThisContract",
      "WCBuyers": [
        {}
      ]
    }
  })

};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

When I test the code in Zapier I get the following error message

```
Failed to run your JavaScript code
Error: Cannot find module 'request' Require stack: - /var/task/index.js - /var/runtime/UserFunction.js - /var/runtime/Runtime.js - /var/runtime/index.js
```

What is the nature of this error and how do I resolve it?

The desired output would be a JSON payload containing the data captured from HubSpot. The Zapier input data tool works very well but I'm not able to see it in action.

Comment: request has been deprecated, As of Feb 11th 2020.

Comment: best to use `fetch` see official `Zapier` docs: https://help.zapier.com/hc/en-us/articles/8496197098253-JavaScript-code-examples-in-Zaps#introductory-examples-0-0